# How can I use pointers to bubble sort values in two arrays in ANSI C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

I am making a small ANSI C application that uses pointers to sort int values using the bubble sort algorithm.

My main file:

```
#include "bubbleSort.h"

char Ar[] = "All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third. All these differ from each other in language, customs and laws. The river Garonne separates the Gauls from the Aquitani; the Marne and the Seine separate them from the Belgae. Of all these, the Belgae are the bravest, because they are furthest from the civilization and refinement of [our] Province, and merchants least frequently resort to them, and import those things which tend to effeminate the mind; and they are the nearest to the Germans, who dwell beyond the Rhine , with whom they are continually waging war; for which reason the Helvetii also surpass the rest of the Gauls in valor, as they contend with the Germans in almost daily battles, when they either repel them from their own territories, or themselves wage war on their frontiers. One part of these, which it has been said that the Gauls occupy, takes its beginning at the river Rhone ; it is bounded by the river Garonne, the ocean, and the territories of the Belgae; it borders, too, on the side of the Sequani and the Helvetii, upon the river Rhine , and stretches toward the north. From 'Caesar's Conquest of Gaul', Translator. W. A. McDevitte. Translator. W. S. Bohn. 1st Edition. New York. Harper & Brothers. 1869. Harper's New Classical Library. Published under creative commons and available at http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0001";

int main(void) {
    int ABStats[ALPHABET_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char chAlphabet[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    char *pAr = Ar;
    char *pAlphabet = chAlphabet;
    int *pABStats = ABStats;

    GetFrequency(pAr, pABStats);
    int i, j;
    for (i = ALPHABET_SIZE-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (*(pABStats+j) < *(pABStats+j+1)) {
                Swap(pABStats+j, pABStats+j-1);
            }
        }
    }

    DisplayVHist(pABStats, ALPHABET_SIZE);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

My bubbleSort.c file:

```
#include "bubbleSort.h"

int GetFrequency(char *pAr, int *pABStats) {
    int chNum = 0;
    for (; *pAr != '\0'; pAr++) {
        char ch = *pAr;
        if (isalpha(ch))
            chNum = (toupper(ch) - 'A');
        pABStats[chNum]++;
    }
    return chNum;
}

void DisplayVHist(int *pABStats, int size) {
    int i, j;
    const float lengthAr = strlen(Ar);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        float chPercent = 100 * (*pABStats / lengthAr);
        printf("'%c' --> %6.3f percent --> %3d occurances --> ", (i + 'A'), chPercent, *pABStats);
        for (j = 0; j < (*pABStats / 2); j++) {
            printf("%c",'*');
        }
        printf("\n");
        pABStats++;
    }
}

void Swap(int *pA, int *pB) {
    int temp;
    temp = *pA;
    *pA = *pB;
    *pB = temp;
}
```

My header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE 26

extern char Ar[];

int GetFrequency(char*, int*);
void DisplayVHist(int*, int);
void Swap(int*, int*);
```

I would like the application to iterate through the array ABStats using the pointer pABStats and use the Sort() function inside bubbleSort.c to sort the values inside ABStats from highest occurrence to lowest occurrence. Everything so far is functioning properly except for my Sort() algorithm.

I am required to use a Bubble Sort algorithm by using the function Sort() inside the bubbleSort.c file. I also have to use pointers to reference the array, as opposed to using ABStats[i].

Does anybody have any advice on how to get Sort() to work? I'm fairly new to C programming. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean these four lines of nested loop by Sort().

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it's supposed to return `-1` if `ch` is not a letter.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar yes I'd like to use the `Sort()` function in bubbleSort.c to sort `ABStats` using the pointer `pABStats`.

Comment: `if (pABStats+j < pABStats+j+1) {
                Swap(pABStats+j, pABStats+j-1);
            }` Conditions and actions are inconsistent.

Comment: @BenjaminC.Huskisson-Snider you can't have a negative array subscript.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm new to C, so you posting that these conditions and actions are inconsistent does not help me. If I knew why, I'd try to fix it.

Comment: @BenjaminC.Huskisson-Snider you should have if (*(pABStats+j) <       *(pABStats+j+1)) . in your code you are comparing two pointers

Comment: you  exchanged a other-data compared the magnitude.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's not always `-1`. I just debugged the value stored.

Comment: @BenjaminC.Huskisson-Snider its irrelevant if its never -1 when you debug the code, the fact is it can be -1 and thats a bug.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Modified the code to remove the possibility of a negative index.

Comment: @tesseract I removed that option. The code has been edited with the change.

Comment: Why do you have to use pointers? And why don't you use a general purpose sort?

Comment: `for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (pABStats+j < pABStats+j+1) {
                Swap(pABStats+j, pABStats+j-1);
            }
        }`, there is confusion do you start from `1` do you start from `0` of `j`. and it need dereference, point out by tesseract. or write simply `pABStats[j] < pABStats[j+1]`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Required by my professor to use pointers and implement bubble sort.

Comment: Why don't you use a general purpose sort that can sort any array? Your code can only sort this one array. Learn to separate sorting code from the data to be sorted. Please define what you mean by "use pointers". Is it enough for your program to declare and use a pointer at some point. Or do the pointers have to be used in a specific way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because my professor has asked for us to specifically use BubbleSort. And I mean to use pointers to reference values, as opposed to using `ABStats[i]` to reference an element in the array.

Comment: Would `*(ABStats+i)` suffice?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No. I have to use the pointer `pABStats` to reference elements.

Comment: chNum = (toascii(toupper(ch)) - 'A'); should be chNum = toupper(ch) - 'A'; the toascii is not necessary

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all. Why would it be better to write `*(pABStats+j)` as you did instead of `pABStats[j]`. No real programmer would ever write the former. I don't think the prof can really want you to do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan He does. I do not know why it's better, nor do I understand its purpose.

Comment: It's not better. It is much worse. If he really means what you understand him to mean you need to find a better teacher.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! Unfortunately I need it as a float or the percentage does not work. `#include <string.h>` got rid of a warning though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is out of my control, sadly.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Typo. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
    if (*(pABStats+j) < *(pABStats+j+1))
        Swap(pABStats+j, pABStats+j-1);
```

Should read:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    if (*(pABStats+j) < *(pABStats+j+1))
        Swap(pABStats+j, pABStats+j+1);
```

Your `for` loop led to out of bounds array access. And you must swap the items that you compared.

I suspect there are other problems with the code but I don't have the energy to debug it all.

Some general points:

1. Sorting could should be de-coupled from the data it operates on. Your sort is inlined into your main. That's not ideal. Take a look at the standard library sorting function to see how it should be done.
2. Whilst your professor seems to think that `*(a+i)` is better than `a[i]` he/she is in a tiny minority. Try not to be misled by this advice. Prefer using the array indexing operator.

Comment: Thank you David! And to everybody else who helped me fix bugs! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
int GetFrequency(char *pAr, int *pABStats) {
int chNum = 0;
for (; *pAr != '\0'; pAr++) { /*check if at the end of the array*/
    char ch = *pAr; /*store current letter as a char*/
    if isalpha(ch) /*if character is a letter*/
        chNum = (toupper(ch) - 'A'); /*return ascii code of specified letter*/
    pABStats[chNum]++; /*store ascii value in array and increment array*/
}
return chNum;
```

}
this makes sense, but then you bubble sort the pABStats array, you are loosing all the information.

suppose there were 10A's and 5B's in your sentence so pABStats[0] = 10 and pABstats[1] = 5, when you bubble sort this from small to large, pABstats[0] = 5 and PabStats[1] = 10. So now your program thinks there were 5A's and 10B's ?

I assume the array subscript runs from 0-25, which translates to subscript 0 is the number of A's and subscript 1 number of B's and so on.

Comment: I am aware of that issue. That is the next thing that I am looking to fix.

Comment: Yes, the array subscript is from `0` to `25`, and index `0` is the number of A's, index `1` is the number of B's, and so on. Eventually I would like this sorted at the same time as `ABStats`, so that it keeps the relationship of frequencies to letters. I have an array called `chAlphabet` and a pointer to it called `pAlphabet` that I plan to use for this purpose.

Comment: If your lecturer has thought you structures, I would look into it. It would be a more elegant solution, but otherwise you should get it to work with your method. good luck.

Comment: He hasn't gone through structures yet. Thank you. Much appreciated.